# How do you reset the 'recenter' button on a Google map after changing the coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google map that starts off at a particular location then you can click a button to change the location. How do I then reset the 'recenter' button so if you click it you go to the second location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: GMap.savePosition() resets the position.